# Ordinary differential equation eigenvalues/eigenfuntions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, eigenfunctions, sturm-liouville

Consider the DE $$y''+\lambda y=0$$ where $\lambda$ is a constant

subject to the boundary conditions $$y(0)=0$$ and $$y(a)=0$$ where $a$ is a positive constant

I want to find the eigenvalues and eigenfunctions related to this problem

My attempt:

The auxiliary equation is $$m^2-\lambda=0\implies m=\sqrt{-\lambda}$$

Thus we have two cases

Case (i)
$$\lambda<0$$ in which we have real different  roots 
so let $$\lambda=-k^2\implies m=\pm k$$
thus the solution is $$y=Ae^{kx}+Be^{-kx}$$

Now when $y(0)=0$ we have that $$0=Ae^{k(0)}+Be^{-k(0)}\implies -B=A$$ since $k\ne 0$

Now when $y(a)=0$ we have that $$0=Ae^{ka}+Be^{-ka}\implies \frac{Ae^{ka}}{e^{-ka}}=-B$$ since $a\ne 0$ thus there are no eigenvalues for when $\lambda <0$

Can anyone tell me if i have made a mistake somewhere in this, because i'm unsure what to do from here, i know the next case to check will be when $\lambda>0$ which would give complex roots, but i would like to know if my approach up to now is correct, thanks for taking the time to read this, and any help would be appreciated also i know that when i multiply through by $$q^*=\frac{1}{a_2}e^{\int\frac{a_1}{a_2}}dx=1$$ thus in normal ?self-adjoint form.

Comment: Yes as $\lambda <0$

Comment: I think first part is right. for the second, $\lambda>0$ gives $m=\pm ik$ (with  $\lambda=k^2$). right!

Comment: Yea I've gotten that it's $y=Acoskx+Bsinkx$

Comment: so you you found the answer. good job.

Comment: It's when I substitute the second condition in I can't seem to  simplify it

Comment: With $y(0)=0$ we see $A=0$. With $y(a)=0$ we see $\sin ka=0$ then $ka=n\pi$ that is $k=\dfrac{n\pi}{k}$.

Comment: finally answer is $y(x)=B\sin\dfrac{n\pi}{a}x$, $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $B\in\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your approach so far is correct. One should also check (preferably first, so you don't forget!) the $\lambda=0$ case: here, it is easy to check that the boundary conditions can't be satisfied.

One can actually extract the general solution from your analysis. In order for there to be a nonzero solution, the system of equations
$$ \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ e^{ka} & e^{-ka} \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} A \\ B \end{pmatrix} = 0 $$
must be degenerate (else the only solution is zero). Hence the determinant of the matrix must vanish; this is
$$ e^{-ka}-e^{ka}=0, $$
or $e^{2ka}=1$. Recalling Euler's formula, this occurs if and only if $2ka=2n\pi i $ for some integer $n$. Hence $k=\frac{n\pi i}{a}$. The condition at zero gives $y=2A\sinh{kx}$, and $\sinh{iz} = i\sin{z}$, so the eigenfunctions are proportional to $\sin{(n\pi x/a)}$, for $n \in \{ 1,2,3,\dotsc\}$. Certainly this *looks* plausible, since this satisfies the equation and boundary conditions.

Comment: can we not use the fact that $A=-B$ so we get $$Ae^ka+Be^{-ka}=0\implies 0=A(e^{-ka}-e^{ka})$$

Comment: It's the same thing, my way just has more emphasis on why the boundary conditions determine $k$, and not one of $A$ or $B$, for example. Either way is fine.

Comment: May I ask how you go from calculating k writing that the condition at zero gives  $y=2Asinhkx$

Comment: That's where one uses $A+B=0$ to note that $B=-A$. Or one can use the other boundary condition, which will give the same result.

Comment: Okay is an orthogonal relation for this problem $$\int sin(\frac{n\pi x}{a})-\int sin(\frac{n\pi x}{a}dx=0$$

Answer (score 0):

I'll suggest a general method that separates the equations at the endpoints. This does not directly answer your question, but the method is worth knowing.

For a solution $y$ of the second order equation $y''+\lambda y$, there is no non-trivial solution with $y(0)=0=y'(0)$. So, by scaling $y$ if necessary, it must be a solution of
$$
                 y''+\lambda y = 0, \;\; y(0)=0,\;\; y'(0)=1,
$$
which has unique solution
$$
                 y_{\lambda}(x) = \frac{\sin(\sqrt{\lambda}x)}{\sqrt{\lambda}}.
$$
This version of the solution works for $\lambda=0$ by taking a limit:
$$
                 y_{0}=\lim_{\lambda\rightarrow 0}y_{\lambda}(x) = x.
$$
(This technique eliminates special cases because the limits always exist.)

Any non-trivial solution of the solution where $y(0)=0=y(a)$ must be a non-zero constant multiple of $y_{\lambda}$, which means that the only values of $\lambda$ for which there are non-trivial solutions must satisfy $y_{\lambda}(a)=0$. $\lambda=0$ does not work, which is easily checked because $y_0(x)=x$ does not vanish at $a$. The non-zero $\lambda$ must satisfy
$$
                \sin(\sqrt{\lambda}a) = 0 \\
             \implies \sqrt{\lambda}a = \pm \pi,\pm 2\pi,\pm 3\pi,\cdots \\
                 \implies \lambda = \frac{n^2\pi^2}{a^2},\;\; n=1,2,3,\cdots.
$$